# How to keep symbols, slash, ... in your document?

Tags: latex

I want to keep all the symbols in my following text in LaTeX. but I don't know which syntax I should use to keep them. Can anybody give a suggestion?

```
/forest # search for forest
/<\/way> # find the tag </way>
v # start the visual mode
?<way # find the begin of the tag -> mark <way> until </way>
D  # delete that tag
```

Comment: If you wish to keep them as-is (including the line breaks), you can use the `verbatim` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in [`verbatim` environment](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/verbatim-environment.html), like this:

```
\begin{verbatim}
...
things you want to keep them as is
...
\end{verbatim}
```

For inline mode, you can use [`\verb` command](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/verb-command.html):

```
\verb=...things you want to keep them as is...=
```

---

Check out [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting) for more info:

> [...] If you use the verbatim environment, everything input between the begin and end commands are processed as if by a typewriter. All spaces and new lines are reproduced as given, and the text is displayed in an appropriate fixed-width font. Any LaTeX command will be ignored and handled as plain text. This is ideal for typesetting program source code. [...]

Comment: FWIW, the `verbatim` package is not required in any of these examples, and it has no effect at all in the second example.

Comment: @You The verbatim environment is supported directly by LaTeX but by loading the verbatim package one gets a better implementation, see [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/verbatim-environment.html). I will remove it for better looking though. Thanks.

Comment: @You For the second example, it does work on my PC. Not sure what's going on here.